# MDX - transpose rows to columns

Tags: ssas, mdx, cross-join

I'm trying to display details from two rows into one using MDX.  If I execute the MDX below, it returns 2 rows, one containing the 998 Key and one containing the 999 Key

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
  [Measures].[FactTableCount] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([DimXXXX].[XXXXKey].[XXXXKey].ALLMEMBERS 
  * ([DimAAAA].[AAAAKey].[AAAAKey],{[DimBBBB].[Key].&[998],[DimBBBB].[Key].&[999]},[DimCCCC].[CCCCKey].[CCCCKey])
  ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DimXXXX].[XXXXKey].&[MyValue] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [FactTable])
```

It returns something like this

```
    (columns [DimXXXX].[XXXXKey], [DimAAAA].[AAAAKey], [DimBBBB].[Key], [DimCCCC].[CCCCKey], [Measures].[FactTableCount])

MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, 998, MyCCCCKey1, 1

MyValue, MyAAAAKey2, 999, MyCCCCKey2, 1
```

However I want to return one row like this

```
`(columns [DimXXXX].[Key], [DimAAAA].[AAAAKey], [DimAAAA].[AAAAKey], [DimBBBB].[Key], [DimBBBB].[Key], [DimCCCC].[CCCCKey], [DimCCCC].[CCCCKey], [Measures].[FactTableCount])

MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, MyAAAAKey2, 998, 999, MyCCCCKey1, MyCCCCKey2, 1
```

Among other things (such as using SETs, putting the 998/999 logic after the ROWS/COLUMNS, etc) I've tried

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
  [Measures].[FactTableCount] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([DimXXXX].[XXXXKey].[XXXXKey].ALLMEMBERS 
  * ([DimAAAA].[AAAAKey].[Key],[DimBBBB].[Key].&[998],[DimCCCC].[CCCCKey].[CCCCKey])
  * ([DimAAAA].[AAAAKey].[Key],[DimBBBB].[Key].&[999],[DimCCCC].[CCCCKey].[CCCCKey])
  ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DimXXXX].[XXXXKey].&[MyValue] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [FactTable])
```

...however because the AAAAKey hierarchy is repeated I receive the error message "The AAAAKey hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function"

Is there a way to do do this ?

Comment: You are basicly trying to break dimensionality and hierarchility of your Set that is the reason for the error. Even if you remove the AAAKey, it is still going for two rows. I can try to help you with it. However I need to know the following 1)Define yor problem genericaly and include some sample excel screens, of how the data should be, 2)The type of measure

Comment: Hi @MoazRub - the problem (generically speaking) is that in reality I am actually returning many columns for a given criteria - so the reason to merge details from two rows into one is because otherwise I would need to return two rows when only a couple of fields are different - note I am also returning a large number for rows so the payload will be potentially, unnecessarily very large.  With regards to the type of measure - I assume you're referring to [Measures].[FactTableCount] - this is more for illustration purposes - the real measures I require are scores, which are of data type integer

Comment: So in the example above these are two diffrent data points ,MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, 998, MyCCCCKey1, 1 ,MyValue, MyAAAAKey2, 999, MyCCCCKey2, 1. Now if the value of the measure is 2, 5 and you want to display both these rows as a single row, the value may be misleading, if it is sum the user will not know who contribute 2 and who 5, sum would be the simplest one ,others would be more misleading

Comment: if the only thing that is diffrent in your rows is the [DimBBBB].[Key]'s value and you want to return half the rows you create a set/calulated member and encapsulate them, then use the set or calculated member here.

Comment: I think I can see what you're saying however the measures are one thing, but the dimension values are another - say Record1:MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, 998, MyCCCCKey1, 2 and Record2: MyValue, MyAAAAKey2, 999, MyCCCCKey2, 5 - I would like to output MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, MyAAAAKey2, 998, 999, MyCCCCKey1, MyCCCCKey2, 2, 5

Comment: I've tried using two SET's - one for the 998 and one for the 999 - however when I add them to the crossjoin I receive the same error message (i.e. "The AAAAKey hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function") - do you have an example of what you mean ?

Comment: So when you say                                                                                             
Record1: MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, 998, MyCCCCKey1, 2                             
Record2: MyValue, MyAAAAKey2, 999, MyCCCCKey2, 5                        
Result MyValue, MyAAAAKey1, MyAAAAKey2, 998, 999, MyCCCCKey1,MyCCCCKey2, 2, 5  , you are looking at two measures one for 998 and the other for 999. If that is the case you should remove [DimBBBB].[Key] from your rows , create two calculated members one for each value

Comment: No - [DimBBBB] is a dimension - 998/999 are substituted for values of [DimBBBB].[Key] on each of the two records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188362/discussion-between-moazrub-and-terrorbight).

Comment: I still don't have a resolution for this - any assistance would be gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment below I have a sample.Let me know if it works.

> I think I can see what you're saying however the measures are one
>   thing, but the dimension values are another - say Record1:MyValue,
>   MyAAAAKey1, 998, MyCCCCKey1, 2 and Record2: MyValue, MyAAAAKey2, 999,
>   MyCCCCKey2, 5 - I would like to output MyValue, MyAAAAKey1,
>   MyAAAAKey2, 998, 999, MyCCCCKey1, MyCCCCKey2, 2, 5

So in the query below I am trying to simulate your problem.

```
select
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
on columns,
non empty
([Customer].[City].[City],{[Product].[Category].&[1],[Product].[Category].&[3]},[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result 
[image]

Now onw way is to take the changing values to columns, "{[Product].[Category].&[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCTY8.jpg),[Product].[Category].&[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW2W5.png)}" in my case and "{[DimBBBB].[Key].&[998],[DimBBBB].[Key].&[999]}" in your case

```
select
{
({[Product].[Category].&[1],[Product].[Category].&[3]},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]),
([Product].[Category].defaultmember,[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity])
}
on columns,
non empty
([Customer].[City].[City],[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result:
[image]

Note how the values are only repeated for the relevent column. This does add an extra column but you rows are now half the orignal count.

Edit: to handle the requirement based on the comment

> 1st row of the grid would be Ballard, Bikes, Mountain Bikes, Road
>   Bikes. The 2nd: Ballard, Clothing, Caps, Gloves. The 3rd: Barstow,
>   Bikes, Road Bikes, null. I want to merge/list the actual dimension
>   values

So to achieve above we have two options. But in either case some manipulation on UI would be required.
1)First option

```
with member 
measures.t 
as (nonempty(existing([Customer].[City].currentmember,[Product].[Category].currentmember,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].members),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(0).item(2).name

member measures.t1
as (nonempty(existing([Customer].[City].currentmember,[Product].[Category].currentmember,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].members),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(1).item(2).name
select
{measures.t,measures.t1}
on columns,
nonempty(([Customer].[City].[City],{[Product].[Category].&[1],[Product].[Category].&[3]}),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

2)The second option,

```
with member 
measures.t1
as 
[Customer].[City].currentmember.name

member measures.t2
as 
[Product].[Category].currentmember.name

member measures.t3 
as (nonempty(existing([Customer].[City].currentmember,[Product].[Category].currentmember,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].members),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(0).item(2).name

member measures.t4
as (nonempty(existing([Customer].[City].currentmember,[Product].[Category].currentmember,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].members),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(1).item(2).name

select
{measures.t1,measures.t2,measures.t3,measures.t4}
on columns,
nonempty(([Customer].[City].[City],{[Product].[Category].&[1],[Product].[Category].&[3]}),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @MoazRub.I can see you've merged rows to move the product values to row headings and listed the corresponding measure values.Taking a step back, what I was wanting to do was to list dimension values - best to ignore the measure values as my issue is with the dimension values. Taking your eg., say I want the first two sub-categories of each category listed, the 1st row of the grid would be Ballard, Bikes, Mountain Bikes, Road Bikes. The 2nd: Ballard, Clothing, Caps, Gloves.  The 3rd: Barstow, Bikes, Road Bikes, null.  I want to merge/list the actual dimension values.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts @MoazRub.With your eg. code I am able to implement the desired behavior.The only issue I have is performance - with a large number of rows/columns the query either takes too long or I get the dreaded "The expression contains a function that cannot operate on a set with more than 4,294,967,296 tuples" - I've tried re-ordering dimension fields, filtering, etc however the tipping point is short of what I'm requesting.An alternative is to combine rows in the business tier of my application - if you have any thoughts I be grateful

Comment: @TerrorBight I know the result would be slow, try replacing the non empty with filter. The basic problem is you are trying to break the fundamentals of how mdx makes set. combining rows would definately be better then the current solution. Plus if the above solution helps you might consider marking it as answer.

Comment: Just to close off - I tried putting some filtering in a variety of places but still had performances issues - I went with combining rows in the business layer of my application - thanks again @MoazRub - I learned a little more about MDX